# css - centering the logo

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to top - center the pinterest logo for just checking purpose. But it is not perfect when I compared with Pinterest website.

Please Check this http://jsfiddle.net/Nwk5Q/embedded/result/

Then go to http://pinterest.com You can see that the logo is somehow differing in the **left** position.

I checked in my computer and saw that it was around 10px difference in the **left** position. Why is it so? I copied the same code which pinterest is using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called scrollbar:-D

Since you have `left:50%` and the standard-scrollbar is `20px` wide, you  are left with `10px` offset;)

You can add

```
body { overflow-y:scroll }
```

to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that in the pinterest website there's a scrollbar that shortens the width of the site.
It pushes everything a bit to the left.

Add the css

```
html { overflow:scroll }
```

And you'll see there's no difference

Answer (score 0):

Did you do this:

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```